# how to get removable storage path in android in all api and all device ? only removable path

Tags: android

System.env("SECONDARY_STORAGE") method not working in some device and Api Level 5.0 up so please anyone help me for how to get path of removable storage in android.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to get high quality answers  you would be better giving a more detailed and specific answer. e.g. "In some device" = which devices; "Not Working" = how do you know it isn't working? What error are you getting?

Comment: its not getting removable path in some device.this some time return null value . or return path of internal storage

Comment: Try with `getExternalFilesDirs()`. If it is not there you are out of luck.

Comment: and how to get path of adoptable storage in Android 6.0